# Set a cell value after sending an email according to the volunteer application status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, mailmerge

I'm in creating a volunteer registration system for the organization  I work with. I want to write a script so that any time I run the script from the dropdown menu, it scans the spreadsheet row by row, and determines what the application status is. If the status is open, I want it to then determine if the status open email has been sent, if it hasn't, send the email, and change the value of the open_email value for that row to "SENT". If the app status is closed, I want it to do the same thing for the closed email.

[Volunteer Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfyDn.png)

Basically, I want to run this function whenever we get new volunteer applications so that they receive emails based on their application status.

I've been successful in writing the function to scan the rows and send the emails based on the application status, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to change the value of the cell after it has sent the corresponding email.

Here is the code for the mail merge function:

```
//function for menu item 1
function volunteerMailMerge() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //references
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ei86oBsafBc6GdFeKFFGdbljyUzbWRFRF8eWvnoYdIU");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Application Status");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange(); //sets range to all data in the spreadsheet
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //translates the range into values in an array
  var headers = values.shift(); //removes headers from values array

  //loop through rows
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var firstName = values[i][0];
    var lastName = values[i][1];
    var email = values[i][2];
    var position = values[i][3];
    var status = values[i][4];

    //mailmerge
    if (status == "OPEN" && openEmail == "") {
          //if app status is open, and openEmail hasn't been sent, do this
          GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "SAFE Volunteer Application",{
                       htmlBody: "email body",
                       });
                       //change value of column 5 on the current row
    } else {};

  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a Google Sheet cell value use [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

> Sets the value of the range. The value can be numeric, string, boolean
>   or date. If it begins with '=' it is interpreted as a formula.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
> var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
> cell.setValue(100);
> ```